# How to reach to a specific computer in a newtork?

Tags: networking, ip, router

Let's say that I have a home network of 5 computers. They all share the same external IP address.
Suppose a machine that is outside the network sends a request (as a client) to one of the 5 computers (this computer will be the server) in this home network. It sends its message to the external IP address. Then, how does the router know to what computer in the home network the message has to be routed to?

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you talk about NAT, there are two main “flavours” - Source NAT & Destination NAT. There is another function called “PAT” (or Port Address Translation).

Source NAT is utilised when all your 5 computers are trying to reach out to the public (Internet) network. At this point your 5 computers get MASQUARADED with your public IPv4 address.

Destination NAT is what you’re asking for. In this case, you must configure your router/firewall (device that holds your public address & maintains your public connection) to “REDIRECT” or “DNAT” all incoming packets destined to a specific application (or port). For instance, if you have an HTTP server running on your private network server with address 10.0.0.3, you simply instruct your router to send all (or selective) TCP packets that have been sent to the public IP on ports 80/443 & send those to 10.0.0.3.

In DNAT scenario you must explicitly instruct your router/firewall about every type of expected, incoming connection. Another example can be that same public address is been used for SMTP server and thus sending all TCP packets received on port 25 to be sent to local server 10.0.0.4 this time. And so on and so forth

That’s in short how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Network Address Translation (NAT) allows a single device, such as a router, to act as an agent between the Internet (or public network) and a local network (or private network), which means that only a single unique IP address is required to represent an entire group of computers to anything outside their network.

ADDRESS TRANSLATION (NAT) OVERLOAD allows your 5 computers to communicate with your router. Each computer has unique private IP address.

When computer1 tries to communicate with website, it sends packet to router.

[image]

Router replace the private IP address (example: 192.168.1.1) with single public IP address (example: 205.65.45.100) but uses same source port number (for example Port 5000) which is used by computer.  It won’t change the source port number.  And Router maintains entry in NAT table.

[image]

The reply from the (web server) internet arrives at your public interface of your router.

[image]

The router accepts packet and check the destination port entry. With the help of the NAT table, your router understands that it belongs to computer1. Router changes single public IP address (example: 205.65.45.100) with your internal private address (example: 192.168.1.1) and your computer receives it.

[image]

This process is applicable for all 5 computers.

Above scenario is only applicable if your computers act as a client. If your computer acts as a server then the solution is “Port forwarding”.

Port forwarding is needed when a machine on the Internet needs to initiate a connection to a machine that's behind a firewall or NAT router.

Refer video for detail information.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K6jMYBfuIY

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is what happens if my computer is the server and not the client. Let's say that a computer outside my home network is the client and it initiates a request to the external IP of my home network. In this case, how does the router know to what computer in the home network to direct the traffic?

Comment: Above scenario is only applicable if your computers act as a client. If your computer acts as a server then the solution is “Port forwarding”.

Comment: Port forwarding is needed when a machine on the Internet needs to initiate a connection to a machine that's behind a firewall or NAT router.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. This was my intention at the original post. I wrote "a machine outside the network sends a request". I thought it was understood that this machine is the client/